# SQL query: extract rows having specific course only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation. How can I extract `AppId` that has only taken C++. and no other course.
Sample data is shown below

```
AppID  | Course
---------------
101    |  C++
101    | Data Structure
100    | C++.
201    | Analysis of Alogrithm
201    | Data Structure
```

and so on

Here is the dummy SQL

```
DROP TABLE #app

CREATE TABLE #app (AppID  int, Course nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO #app 
VALUES(101,'C++'),
(101  ,'Data Structure'),
(100  ,'C++'),
(201  ,'Analysis of Alogrithm'),
(201  ,'Data Structure')

Select AppId,Course From #app
```

Comment: Add `WHERE  Course = 'C++'` to your query, if that really was your question? I guess you forgot to add something.

Comment: voting to close, you don't give full information and write cryptic full caps comments under the only real solution to your current question

Comment: This is a typical high school SQL question. It should be voted down since this is cheating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work

```
select AppId from #app a
where 
AppId in (select AppId from #app where Course='C++') and
1 = (select count(course) from #app where AppId=a.AppId)
```

Comment: This query has a dependent subquery, that is, the subquery is different for each row of the query. The point is that this query probably run in O(n^2), being very dependent on the optimizer of the execution tree.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT
    AppId, 
    Course, 
    count(*) as Total
FROM
    #app
WHERE
    AppId in (SELECT AppId FROM #app WHERE Course='C++')
GROUP BY
    AppId,
    Course
HAVING
    Total = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select AppId from your_table where course = 'C++.';
```

Comment: I only want `100` from this data

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to extract the 100 in this case (The only entry that has only C++ as a course). You could use

```
SELECT AppID from #app WHERE Course=C++
MINUS
SELECT AppID from #app WHERE Course!=C++
```

This should delete those AppIDs that also have other courses.

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Course='C++'
```

Or, if your table containing the Course & AppID field has additional fields, but you're only looking to pull data relating to AppID and Course, you could do.

```
SELECT AppID, Course FROM table_name WHERE Course='C++'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL Query also

```
select AppId from #app
where Course='C++' and Course not in(select Course from #app where Course!='C++')
group by AppId
```